# Create 2-dimensional vectors from 1-dimensionals

Tags: clojure

Although my question seems to be concerned with a rather trivial task, I was not yet able to sucessfully create a single 2-dimensional vector

`[[1 2] [3 4]]`

fom two individual vectors,

`(def a [1 2])` and `(def b [3 4])`.

Leaving the functions `conj` and `cons` aside, I ran into the problem that `vec` or `into-array` both expect single input values.
Another workaround would be pre-filling a two dimenstional vector

`(vec (replicate 2 (vec (replicate 2 nil))))`

but I it is still a complicated option.

Comment: I can't find the `con` function you mentioned. Did you mean `cons`?

Comment: Yes, I corrected that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `vector`:

```
(def a [1 2])
(def b [3 4])
(vector a b) => [[1 2] [3 4]]
[a b] => [[1 2] [3 4]]
```

Comment: I was almost certain i have tried that option as well. Seems I still have missed it though... Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to approach this:

1. As @MartinPůda says, use `vector`: `(vector a b) => [[1 2] [3 4]])`
2. Use `conj`: `(conj [] a b) => [[1 2] [3 4]]`
3. Use a vector literal: `[a b] => [[1 2] [3 4]]`

If Clojure has a problem it is an excess of riches. :-)